# Why doesn't this SQL query work when I use bindValue with $_POST[]?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This php code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM author WHERE id = :id';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
echo $_POST['id'];
$s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
$s->execute();
$result = $s->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Outputs:

```
1 Array ( )
```

If instead of using :id in the sql query I use simply '1', which is the value of $_POST['id']:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM author WHERE id = 1'; //for testing purposes
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
echo $_POST['id'];
$s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
$s->execute();
$result = $s->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

The code outputs:

```
1 Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Kevin Yank [0] => Kevin Yank ) )
```

Which is the expected result. Seeing that the value of $_POST['id'] is 1 which is correct (the echo in the code), I don't understand what is the problem. Maybe you guys can help me?
Cheers

Edit, the html/form:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($authors as $author):?>
  <li>
      <form action="" method="post">
          <div>
               <p>
                  <?php echo htmlout($author['name']); ?>
              </p>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="                              
                  <?php echo $author['id'] ?>">
              <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
          </div>
     </form>
 </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit 2:
Using the same syntax on a different table works and I dont understand why:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM joke WHERE authorid = :id';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
$s->execute();

$result = $s->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

There are the tables:
The author table (the table that the code doesn't work on):

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The joke table (the code works on this one):

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| joketext | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| jokedate | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| authorid | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the rows on the author table:

```
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| id | name       | email                 |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Kevin Yank | thatguy@kevinyank.com |
|  2 | Joan Smith | joan@example.com      |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
```

I really dont get it.

Comment: post the html/form for this, if you are using one. You're probably using a GET method for it, but we won't know that for sure.

Comment: You should declare the type when you bind as well `$s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: your POST array is a string btw, not an integer

Comment: I addded the html as requested

Comment: When you view the source of your HTML are the id values populated?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, the type argument of bound parameters is ignored in the MySQL PDO driver. It's important in other PDO drivers.

Comment: @BillKarwin Oh, interesting

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Yes they are populated.

Comment: Edited to add some db details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is how you're printing out the ID in the value field in your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="                              
    <?php echo $author['id'] ?>">
```

That actually prints out the ID starting with white spaces, a line break and the indention in the value, so you're basically trying to match this query:

```
SELECT name FROM author WHERE id = '
    1'
```

#### Solution

Either fix the HTML (which I would recommend):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $author['id'] ?>">
```

or simply trim the value when you're using it:

```
$s->bindValue(':id', trim($_POST['id']));
```

I did tried this with the original code in your question and this did indeed fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, this work, BUT I really don't undestand why this code worked even with the html white space:

Comment: @user8217653 According to your question, it didn't. It only worked when you hard coded the ID in the query.

Comment: I can't post it here, the code that worked even with the error it's on the main question.

Comment: yes the original code did not worked, but there is another code with similar syntax only different table, that worked even though the white space in html existed.

Comment: I can't answer that. I just know that this was the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to Filter the ID is number or Alpha.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
//Replace your Code by Ajmal Praveen
$id = $_POST['id']; //If you Need filter? sanitize or i can help u
//PDO prepared statement against Sql injection and Speed
$sql = "SELECT name FROM author WHERE id = :id";
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':id', $id);
$s->execute();
//fetching it
$result = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

echo $result['id'];
echo $result['name'];
?>
```

what ever you need to fetch from the db
use `$result['bla bla']`

Comment: I did, same result, assigning $_POST['id'] to a variable and then using that variable in bindValue doesn't change anything unfortunately :(

Comment: I have re updated the code to grab 1 user DATA to fetch all. but i want to ask that ID is unique user id or something id was provided? because if its wrong everything will wrong. can you give the sql db detail?

Comment: Still doesn't work, I added db details and a code that works on the main post. Thank you for your interest

Comment: Okay i can see someone is replied. So now i want to know whether You have fixed or still facing the issue?

Comment: Fixed, but issue is weird, since other code worked with the html bug. Thanks